# How to change trimmed paper size mid-document with the same stock paper size

Tags: pdftex, memoir, page

Basically what the subject says.

The MWE I have included lists all possible factors that can prevent the solution not being correct:

Not_blank.tex

```
\blankpage

\eject \pdfpagewidth=5.5in \pdfpageheight=8.5in

\begin{center}
    text
\end{center}

\clearpage

\begin{center}
    text
\end{center}

\eject \pdfpagewidth=7in \pdfpageheight=10in

\blankpage
\clearpage
```

Extract of packages.tex

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=7in, paperheight=10in, showframe]{geometry}
```

Extract of papersetup.tex

```
\setstocksize{10in}{7in}
\settrimmedsize{10in}{7in}{*}
\setbinding{0.250in}
```

Extract of preamble.tex

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\checkandfixthelayout\fixpdflayout
```

Extract of main.tex

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
```

I tried doing a Google search, but nothing came up.

Edit: I have already used `\setbinding` for the page (recto)

Picture of what it's supposed to look like (with showframe):

[image]

Picture of what it currently looks like (with showframe):

[image]

Comment: The `geometry` package allows one, in the middle of a document, to change both the page layout (margins/etc) as well as the paper size, if desired.

Comment: As far as I have read the documentation, it doesn't change the trim size.

Comment: The geometry package assumes that the stock size is the same as the trim size.

Comment: Haven't used them, but I think the `crop` package as well as the `pdfpages` package allow the introduction of crop marks for setting the trim size.

Comment: Can you edit the project for me?

Comment: Please post the code for your MWE here. Your question will be useless to other people when the contents of the link changes: questions should be self-contained. Occasionally, that's not possible for the posting of log files or class files, for example, but the document should be in the question - in minimal form, obviously.

Comment: There's also that `z`-something pages package, which seems to support more of these kinds of professional-printing-press type options. Not certain about `typearea`. It isn't entirely clear what you require the result to look like. Is it that you want crop/trim marks? So just changing the margins, say, isn't sufficient. Or what?

Comment: @cfr See changes in my post

Comment: Please make your fragments into an example people can copy-paste compile. What you've posted is certainly not a minimal working example, as it is not working at all.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you rightly, then you can use the standard `memoir` commands to change the document page layout.

The only catch is that the size of the type set text block isn't automatically changed by memoir. Changing this mid-document can be a bit tricky, but you can copy what the `geometry` package does to do this provided you also surround things with a couple of `\newpage` commands.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setstocksize{7in}{5in}
\settrimmedsize{7in}{5in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{.5in}{1in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\makeatletter
% adapted from \Gm@changelayout geometry.sty
\newenvironment{newlayout}[1]{%
  \newpage
  #1%
  \setlength{\@colht}{\textheight}
  \setlength{\@colroom}{\textheight}%
  \setlength{\vsize}{\textheight}
  \setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
  \if@twocolumn%
    \advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
    \divide\columnwidth\tw@%
    \@firstcolumntrue%
  \fi%
  \setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}%
  \setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}}{\newpage}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{newlayout}{%
  \setstocksize{6in}{4in}
  \settrimmedsize{6in}{4in}{*}
  \setlrmarginsandblock{.5in}{1in}{*}
  \setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
  \checkandfixthelayout
  \fixpdflayout}
\lipsum[2]
\end{newlayout}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although it worked, I was hoping for a solution that changed the paper size of the pdf too. Should I already accept the answer?

Comment: Set the stock size to the same as the trim size and remove the `\settrims` lines. I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: By the way, your comment suggest you misunderstand the difference between stock size and trim size. The stock size is the size of the piece of paper you print on to. It might include some bleed. The trim size is the size that you cut down to and is therefore the final size of the page you want. Then you have (in `memoir` speak) the type block size which is the trim size less margins. In my first answer I left the pdf page size the same because you explicitly asked for the stock size to remain the same.

Comment: @TeokanDuranDemircan If your purpose is commercial printing, especially when using PDF/X technology, then you cannot change either paper size (MediaBox) or trim size (TrimBox) within the PDF. Even if TeX lets you do it, the result is off-spec. Although you did not originally ask about that, I put this comment for the benefit of others who find this thread via search.

Comment: I would print all the pages in letter-sized paper then I would trim it down to 7" by 10" and 8.5" by 5.5". I wanted to have the pdf page with the trimmed down sizes, and not the stock size which is essentially the same.

And @RobtAll, I am only printing a few copies for my friends directly from my inkjet printer. No commercial stuff involved.

Comment: @TeokanDuranDemircan The entire PDF area is the "MediaBox." At the same size or smaller is the "CropBox," which is the area visible in PDF reader software. At the same size or smaller than that, is the "TrimBox," which is the finished size on paper. The boundary of the TrimBox is invisible, but is understood by automated curring machines. Since you are not an automated cutting machine, you are probably interested in the CropBox. The CropBox can be changed per-page, and Adobe Acrobat Pro can do it. But I have searched, and am not certain that TeX can do it without code hack.

Comment: @TeokanDuranDemircan The pdf page size is the paper size, which is the stock size. So your question requires keeping this the same. What do *you* mean by the pdf page size? If not the paper size, then what? It seems that you probably want something you've not asked for and are dissatisfied with something that is what you asked for ;).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly many years ago Donald Arseneau Gave a general solution to changing the layout mid-document along the lines:

```
% single column text
text
\doublecolumn
% change the layout
\singlecolumn% back to where were
single column text
```

but if initially double column text than swap `\doublecolumn` and `\singlecolumn`.

I think that a generalisation of this is:

```
text
\clearpage
% change page layout
\clearpage
more text in the new layout
```