# Memoir changing page size mid-document

Tags: memoir, tex-core, page

Obviously I'm a bit new to latex (using xelatex engine), just trying out the ground to see if I can transition to it.

I need to change page size mid-document. The document will not be printed, it's only going to be viewed through a PDF viewer.

So far the closest to the solution was this post:
[How to change trimmed paper size mid-document with the same stock paper size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407343/how-to-change-trimmed-paper-size-mid-document-with-the-same-stock-paper-size)

But it doesn't really work. Here's my naive version of that code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setstocksize{7in}{5in}
\settrimmedsize{7in}{5in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{.5in}{1in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\makeatletter
% adapted from \Gm@changelayout geometry.sty
\newenvironment{newlayout}[1]{%
    \newpage
    #1%
    \setlength{\@colht}{\textheight}
    \setlength{\@colroom}{\textheight}%
    \setlength{\vsize}{\textheight}
    \setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
    \if@twocolumn%
    \advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
    \divide\columnwidth\tw@%
    \@firstcolumntrue%
    \fi%
    \setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}}{\newpage}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\let\fixpdflayout\mem@fixpagelayout
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{newlayout}{%
            \pdfpagewidth=297mm
            \pdfpageheight=420mm
            \setstocksize{420mm}{297mm}
            \settrimmedsize{420mm}{297mm}{1}
            \setlrmarginsandblock{15mm}{30mm}{1}
            \setulmarginsandblock{30mm}{30mm}{1}
            \checkandfixthelayout
            \fixpdflayout}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{newlayout}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

If you look at the A3 page text doesn't actually fit the boundaries set by memoir and that's what I want to fix, but am absolutely clueless as to how.

inb4: pdfpages (I want a single tex file to rule them all, otherwise transitioning to latex doesn't really make sense for me)

Comment: the page layout looks ok (it has the values you asked for), but the frame (made by the showframe package) looks faulty. Imho showframe (eso-pic) doesn't expect an oneside layout which has different left + right margins.

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/rolfn/eso-pic/issues/5

Comment: Thank you for your help.